# Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null, what is happening?

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

My problem seems to lie somewhere in between the subfunction calling of LoadXML. It seems that the xml data becomes null for some weird reason, and I have no idea how to fix that. Stackexchange seemed to have loads of similar questions but many were unanswered or the answer they had did not help my case.

```
function load() {
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var idname = document.getElementById("name").value;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this); //it obtains it here...
            LoadXML(this, idname);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "helper_database.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function LoadXML(xml, name) {
    var x, i, xmlDoc, nametxt, areEqual;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    nametxt = name;
    console.log("HERE \n" + xmlDoc); //...but it becomes null.
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name"); //this returns the error of "Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null"
    console.log("muuttujan x eka: " + x[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (areEqual = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name").toUpperCase() === nametxt.toUpperCase()) {
            document.getElementById("ComFocus").value = x[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the helper_database.xml

```
<Character>
    <name>test</name>
    <stats>
        <Com>1</Com>
        <Con>2</Con>
        <Cun>3</Cun>
        <Dex>4</Dex>
        <Mag>5</Mag>
        <Per>6</Per>
        <Str>7</Str>
        <Wil>8</wil>
    </stats>
</Character>
```

Comment: It's just a typo (I'm surprised that you aren't getting an error in the web console, but I don't either): The XML is malformed: `<Wil>8</wil>` Note that the end tag is `wil`, not `</Wil>`. Fix that and it parses and `responseXML` is filled in.

Comment: Rather than stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, I suggest turning on the lights using the fully-featured debugger built into your browser. Using that, you could look at `this` in your `onreadystatechange` handler and see that its `responseXML` property is `null`.

Comment: Like T.J. Crowder wrote it is a type in XML file. Additionally you will get problems on the equal check. `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")` is a collection so there will be no `.toUpperCase()`. You have to do something like that `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase()` or shorter `x[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase()`

Comment: In addition to the other comments, given `xmlhttp.open("GET", "helper_database.xml", false);` which does a synchronous request, there is no need to set up an `onreadystatechange` event handler at all, you could as well try to process the response after the `send()` call. In general, you should try to use asynchronous requests by using `xmlhttp.open("GET", "helper_database.xml", true)`, then the onreadystatechange handler at least makes sense.

Comment: I appreciate very much all of these comments and feedback. I did not know that xml tags are case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some typeo as well as some parsing errors.
Note that :

- `getElementsByTagName().toUpperCase` is invalid because gEBTN returns array of objects. so, you have to use `getElementsByTagName()[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase()`.
- instead of using `console.log("muuttujan x eka: " + x[0]);`, use `console.log("muuttujan x eka: " + x[0].innerHTML);`

```js
function load() {
  var xmlhttp;
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var idname = document.getElementById("name").value;
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log(xmlhttp); //it obtains it here...
      LoadXML(xmlhttp, idname);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "helper_database.xml", false);
  //xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function LoadXML(xml, name) {
  var x, i, xmlDoc, nametxt, areEqual;
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  nametxt = name;
  console.log("HERE \n" + xmlDoc); //...but it becomes null.
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name"); //this returns the error of "Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null"
  console.log("muuttujan x eka: " + x[0].innerHTML);
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (areEqual = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase() === nametxt.toUpperCase()) {
      document.getElementById("ComFocus").value = x[i];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="name" onblur="load();" />
    <div id="ComFocus"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Character><name>test</name>
<stats>
<Com>1</Com>
<Con>2</Con>
<Cun>3</Cun>
<Dex>4</Dex>
<Mag>5</Mag>
<Per>6</Per>
<Str>7</Str>
<Wil>8</Wil>
</stats></Character>
```